# Deletar valores iguais dentro de um array dinamico

Tags: php, array, string

Tenho um array com vários nomes dinâmicos que podem mudar a cada momento, qual a maneira mais correta  de percorrer esse array e criar uma condição para exclui-los iguail? (no caso dois elementos com mesmo nome)

Ja tinha visto algo parecido aqui mas era pra elementos fixos, eu queria criar uma condição no qual eu desse unset(comando para remover um elemento do array) no elemento repetido, um exemplo do que eu quero mais ou menos abaixo:

```
$array = ('pepsi','Coca','fanta','pepsi');
// verificaria se tem elemento igual
if( "a operação que estou na duvida"){
//daria unset em um dos valores duplicados
    unset($array["3"]);
} 
// uso pra ignorar as chaves do array e alinhar 
$array = array_values( $array );
```

Obs: Os valores so para exemplo, meu array pode ter `n` valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O php já possui uma função que faz tudo o que você quer:

```
array_unique($array);
```

Ele remove as duplicatas e reordena os indíces do array.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NDxTHL).

- **Veja o `array_unique()` na [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php).**

Comment: Poxa, não tinha conhecimento dessa função, obrigado !